# Proof of $\frac{Y^{\lambda}-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\to Z\sim N(0,1)$ in distribution as $\lambda\to\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

This is an exercise of the Central Limit Theorem:

> Let $Y^{\lambda}$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda>0$.
>   Prove that $\frac{Y^{\lambda}-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\to Z\sim N(0,1)$ in distribution as $\lambda\to\infty$.

I've done that 
$$
Z_n\to Z\sim N(0,1)
$$
in distribution using the CLT, where $Z_n=(Y^n-n)/\sqrt{n}$. Some naive attempt to go is considering 
$$
Y^{n}\leq Y^{\lambda}\leq Y^{n+1}\tag{*}
$$
where $n\leq\lambda\leq n+1$ and somehow use the squeeze theorem. But both (*) and the squeeze theorem in convergence in distribution are NOT justified. How can I go on? Or do I need an alternative direction?

Comment: Since only a narrow special case of the CLT would be needed, I wouldn't be surprised if it can be done directly without knowing the CLT is true in general.

Comment: Your proposition labeled $(*)$ is of course not true if it's an inequality on the values of the random variables.  But if $\le$ means "is stochastically smaller than" then it's true.  However, if you can show $\Pr(Y^\lambda=y)$ is between the corresponding probabilities with $n$ and $n+1$ in place of $\lambda$, then maybe it will work.

Comment: Proposition $(\ast)$ can be made fully rigorous using the natural coupling of a whole family of Poisson random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The squeeze theorem in convergence in distribution can be made fully rigorous in the situation you describe--but the shortest proof here might be through characteristic functions.

Recall that if $Y^\lambda$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, $\varphi_\lambda(t)=\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itY^\lambda})$ is simply $\varphi_\lambda(t)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda(1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm it})}$. Thus $\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itZ^\lambda})=\mathrm e^{-\mathrm it\sqrt{\lambda}}\varphi_\lambda(t/\sqrt{\lambda})=\mathrm e^{-g_\lambda(t)}$ with
$$
g_\lambda(t)=\mathrm it\sqrt{\lambda}+\lambda-\lambda\mathrm e^{\mathrm it/\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
Expanding the exponential up to second order yields
$$
g_\lambda(t)=\mathrm it\sqrt{\lambda}+\lambda-\lambda\cdot(1+\mathrm it/\sqrt{\lambda}-t^2/2\lambda)+o(1)\to\tfrac12t^2.
$$
Thus, for every $t$, $\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itZ^\lambda})\to\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}=\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itZ})$ where $Z$ is standard normal, hence $Z^\lambda\to Z$ in distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Are you using Levy's Continuity Theorem to conclude that convergence of characteristic function here implies convergence in distribution?

Comment: Yes, since the pointwise limit itself is a characteristic function.

Comment: How can we use taylor expansion with complex number? My main concern is how do we get $o(1)$

Comment: @strikal "How can we use taylor expansion with complex number?" Sorry, I do not follow. What is the problem with Taylor expansions for complex valued functions?

Comment: I didn't use Taylor expansions for complex values, therefore I don't get why there is $o(1)$ in the last line

Comment: @strikal This uses simply that $e^z=1+z+z^2/2+|z|^2\epsilon(z)$ for some function $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon(z)\to0$ when $z\to0$.