# Showing $ \mathbb{P}\Big( \frac{\Pi - \lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\leq x \Big) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, characteristic-functions

Let $\Pi$ be a random variable distributed by Poisson  distribution with parameter $\lambda>0.$ Need to show that $$ \mathbb{P}\Big( \frac{\Pi - \lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\leq x \Big)  \rightarrow_{\lambda \to \infty}  \Phi(x)$$ for every  $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

I have no idea what to do and how to start. I know that Poisson random variable $exp(iat + \lambda(e^{ibt-1})$ maybe this is equal to $\Phi(t)$ but than what is $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Central limit theorem is an answer for your question.

Comment: Look the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245379/proof-of-fracy-lambda-lambda-sqrt-lambda-to-z-sim-n0-1-in-distrib?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the central limit theorem and the fact that exponentials transform sums in products.